# Is it possible to send OSC commands to an iPad via the Camera Connection Kit?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, osc

I'm building a small controller device that I'd like to partner with a computer. I've settled on using OSC out from my custom built hardware and am pretty satisfied with what I can get from WOscLib. Two goals I'd like to achieve are portability and a very nice ratio between battery:computing power, and this has lured me towards using iPhoneOS to accomplish my goals.

I think the iPad would suit my needs perfectly, except that using wifi to broadcast OSC out from my device requires that device to be connected to a third device with a wifi chip, and this would destroy the goal of portability, whilst also introducing potential latency and stability headaches. My question is pretty simple: *Can I push OSC commands FROM my controller TO an iPad via USB and the Camera Connection Kit?* If I could accomplish this, the two major goals of my project would be fulfilled very nicely.

This seems like it should be a simple little question, but researching this obsessively over the past few weeks has left me more almost more uncertain than if I had done no research at all. I'd really like some more confidence before I go down this route, and it seems like it should be possible. Any insight would be very, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't :-(
In order to interface your custom hw you'll have to
obtain a license from apple.

Comment: This isn't true anymore, the OP could conceivably connect the custom device via wired ethernet to the iPad CCK: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202034

Answer (score 0):

no third device is required.  you can click "create network" on your wifi menu in osx and then you ipad can connect directly to that.  many apps now use osc over wifi on the ipad.  some are done in java.  im not sure about objective c.

Answer (score 0):

You could connect a USB ethernet device to the iPad Camera Connection Kit and send OSC over ethernet from your custom controller.

Somewhere along the line since this question was asked, [USB ethernet devices became officially supported over the CCK.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202034)